# SIGSEGV crash without any direct trace of my app's code

Tags: objective-c, macos, crash, nswindow, segmentation-fault

Several users of one of my apps are having random crashes. The crash log doesn't contain any reference to methods written by myself and hence, is hard to read. Also the crash is very hard to reproduce so I can't use tooling such as NSZombieEnabled to gain more information.

Based on the crash report (see below) I have the assumption it's because my app's NSWindow object is requested (or informed) to resize in an animated way (hence, the timer and delay information) but there's a button (NSButton) that is causing an issue (probably it's deallocated since I'm having a SIGSEGV). However, I don't understand why the reason is "Selector name found in current argument registers: methodForSelector:".

Can you reveil more useful information from this crash log allowing me to understand what's causing this issue?

```
Exception Type:  SIGSEGV
Exception Codes: SEGV_MAPERR at 0x295eeda4bec0
Crashed Thread:  0

Application Specific Information:
Selector name found in current argument registers: methodForSelector:

Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib     0x00007fff848c70dd objc_msgSend + 29
1   AppKit              0x00007fff833a6aef safeARCWeaklyStore + 113
2   AppKit              0x00007fff833b2a5b -[NSActionCell setTarget:] + 99
3   AppKit              0x00007fff83610de1 -[NSActionCell copyWithZone:] + 285
4   AppKit              0x00007fff83611157 -[NSButtonCell copyWithZone:] + 98
5   AppKit              0x00007fff8360f81b -[NSButton baselineOffsetFromBottom] + 370
6   AppKit              0x00007fff835289c6 -[NSView(NSConstraintBasedLayout) nsli_lowerAttribute:intoExpression:withCoefficient:forConstraint:] + 750
7   Foundation          0x00007fff8b86f003 lower_1_attribute + 157
8   Foundation          0x00007fff8b86e9e6 -[NSLayoutConstraint _lowerIntoExpression:reportingConstantIsRounded:] + 101
9   Foundation          0x00007fff8b86e686 -[NSLayoutConstraint _containerGeometryDidChange] + 87
10  AppKit              0x00007fff8341b8c6 _NSViewEnumerateConstraints + 252
11  AppKit              0x00007fff8352854b __52-[NSView(NSConstraintBasedLayout) _setLayoutEngine:]_block_invoke_2 + 322
12  Foundation          0x00007fff8b86e48e -[NSISEngine withBehaviors:performModifications:] + 154
13  AppKit              0x00007fff833ca1aa -[NSView(NSConstraintBasedLayout) _withAutomaticEngineOptimizationDisabled:] + 69
14  AppKit              0x00007fff835283e8 __52-[NSView(NSConstraintBasedLayout) _setLayoutEngine:]_block_invoke + 481
15  AppKit              0x00007fff83401bcf -[NSView(NSConstraintBasedLayout) _setLayoutEngine:] + 232
16  AppKit              0x00007fff835284e0 __52-[NSView(NSConstraintBasedLayout) _setLayoutEngine:]_block_invoke_2 + 215
17  Foundation          0x00007fff8b86e48e -[NSISEngine withBehaviors:performModifications:] + 154
18  AppKit              0x00007fff833ca1aa -[NSView(NSConstraintBasedLayout) _withAutomaticEngineOptimizationDisabled:] + 69
19  AppKit              0x00007fff835283e8 __52-[NSView(NSConstraintBasedLayout) _setLayoutEngine:]_block_invoke + 481
20  AppKit              0x00007fff83401bcf -[NSView(NSConstraintBasedLayout) _setLayoutEngine:] + 232
21  AppKit              0x00007fff835284e0 __52-[NSView(NSConstraintBasedLayout) _setLayoutEngine:]_block_invoke_2 + 215
22  Foundation          0x00007fff8b86e48e -[NSISEngine withBehaviors:performModifications:] + 154
23  AppKit              0x00007fff833ca1aa -[NSView(NSConstraintBasedLayout) _withAutomaticEngineOptimizationDisabled:] + 69
24  AppKit              0x00007fff835283e8 __52-[NSView(NSConstraintBasedLayout) _setLayoutEngine:]_block_invoke + 481
25  AppKit              0x00007fff83401bcf -[NSView(NSConstraintBasedLayout) _setLayoutEngine:] + 232
26  AppKit              0x00007fff835284e0 __52-[NSView(NSConstraintBasedLayout) _setLayoutEngine:]_block_invoke_2 + 215
27  Foundation          0x00007fff8b86e48e -[NSISEngine withBehaviors:performModifications:] + 154
28  AppKit              0x00007fff833ca1aa -[NSView(NSConstraintBasedLayout) _withAutomaticEngineOptimizationDisabled:] + 69
29  AppKit              0x00007fff835283e8 __52-[NSView(NSConstraintBasedLayout) _setLayoutEngine:]_block_invoke + 481
30  AppKit              0x00007fff83401bcf -[NSView(NSConstraintBasedLayout) _setLayoutEngine:] + 232
31  AppKit              0x00007fff835281df make_and_host_engine + 248
32  AppKit              0x00007fff83ced3ce -[NSView(NSConstraintBasedLayout) _rebuildLayoutFromScratch] + 134
33  AppKit              0x00007fff83b6fd91 -[NSWindow _setWindowResolution:displayIfChanged:] + 279
34  AppKit              0x00007fff83739361 -[NSWindow _updateInheritedBackingScaleFactorAndDisplayIfChanged:] + 131
35  AppKit              0x00007fff83609237 __67-[NSWindow _updateSettingsSendingScreenChangeNotificationIfNeeded:]_block_invoke + 193
36  AppKit              0x00007fff83482bdb NSPerformWithScreenUpdatesDisabled + 64
37  AppKit              0x00007fff8346c4c6 -[NSWindow _updateSettingsSendingScreenChangeNotificationIfNeeded:] + 365
38  AppKit              0x00007fff83469b54 -[NSWindow _setFrame:updateBorderViewSize:] + 1098
39  AppKit              0x00007fff8346912c -[NSWindow _oldPlaceWindow:] + 1117
40  AppKit              0x00007fff8346851d -[NSWindow _setFrameCommon:display:stashSize:] + 2561
41  AppKit              0x00007fff83560be3 -[NSWindow setValue:forKey:] + 180
42  Foundation          0x00007fff8b84f9d1 -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forKeyPath:] + 338
43  AppKit              0x00007fff8365c926 _NSStopAnimation + 98
44  AppKit              0x00007fff8365c1fb __40+[NSAnimationManager performAnimations:]_block_invoke_2 + 756
45  AppKit              0x00007fff83482bdb NSPerformWithScreenUpdatesDisabled + 64
46  AppKit              0x00007fff8365beff __40+[NSAnimationManager performAnimations:]_block_invoke + 129
47  AppKit              0x00007fff8365ba66 +[NSAnimationManager performAnimations:] + 1155
48  AppKit              0x00007fff8358cbf6 -[NSScreenDisplayLink _fire] + 398
49  CoreFoundation      0x00007fff8d76b2e4 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 19
50  CoreFoundation      0x00007fff8d76af73 __CFRunLoopDoTimer + 1058
51  CoreFoundation      0x00007fff8d7de53d __CFRunLoopDoTimers + 300
52  CoreFoundation      0x00007fff8d726608 __CFRunLoopRun + 2023
53  CoreFoundation      0x00007fff8d725bd8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 295
54  HIToolbox           0x00007fff8fc4356f RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 234
55  HIToolbox           0x00007fff8fc432ea ReceiveNextEventCommon + 430
56  HIToolbox           0x00007fff8fc4312b _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter + 70
57  AppKit              0x00007fff834278ab _DPSNextEvent + 977
58  AppKit              0x00007fff83426e58 -[NSApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 345
59  AppKit              0x00007fff8341caf3 -[NSApplication run] + 593
60  AppKit              0x00007fff83399244 NSApplicationMain + 1831
61  libdyld.dylib       0x00007fff891e25c9 start + 0

Thread 0 crashed with X86-64 Thread State:
rip: 0x00007fff848c70dd    rbp: 0x00007fff57ac7fd0    rsp: 0x00007fff57ac7f98    rax: 0x0000000000000001 
rbx: 0x00007fff83d68df7    rcx: 0x00007fff833a7973    rdx: 0x00007fff83d68df7    rdi: 0x000060000011a820 
rsi: 0x00007fff83d66b5c     r8: 0x0000000000000000     r9: 0xffffffffffffffff    r10: 0x00007fff83d66b5c 
r11: 0x0000295eeda4bea8    r12: 0x000060000011a820    r13: 0x00007fff848c70c0    r14: 0x00006000002e2d28 
r15: 0x0000000000000000 rflags: 0x0000000000010202     cs: 0x000000000000002b     fs: 0x0000000000000000 
gs: 0x0000000000000000
```

Thanks!

Comment: Try to dissasembly your binary and look if any value in the registers point to a valid address (after subtracting load address)

Answer (score 1):

Xcode 6+ has an awesome feature to list users crashes and re simulate them in your iphone or simulator check it out ... hopefully it helps or you gotta do it in the hard way to trace down by "demystification"

http://www.raywenderlich.com/23704/demystifying-ios-application-crash-logs

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/AnalyzingCrashReports/AnalyzingCrashReports.html

Answer (score 0):

I'm no expert, but here are my guesses...

```
-[NSWindow _updateInheritedBackingScaleFactorAndDisplayIfChanged:]
```

... Perhaps the screen resolution has just changed?  Eg the user made a change in System Preferences > Displays, or perhaps dragged your app's window from a non-retina to a retina display?

```
Selector name found in current argument registers: methodForSelector:

Thread 0 Crashed:
objc_msgSend
safeARCWeaklyStore
-[NSActionCell setTarget:]
-[NSActionCell copyWithZone:]
-[NSButtonCell copyWithZone:]
-[NSButton baselineOffsetFromBottom]
-[NSView(NSConstraintBasedLayout) nsli_lowerAttribute:intoExpression:withCoefficient:forConstraint:]
```

... Auto Layout is recalculating the layout, and asked an `NSButton` in the app for `baselineOffsetFromBottom`.  This caused the button to ask for a copy of the `NSButtonCell` (I don't know why).  Whilst making the copy, `NSButtonCell` tried to set the `target` of the copy, but there was a problem here.  Perhaps it was using `methodForSelector:` to read the target address in order to write it into the copy?

Is it possible you have an `NSButton` without a target set?  Or is it declared as `weak`, whereas `strong` is necessary here?

I expect most of this is wrong, but perhaps it helps the thought process... good luck...